# How to attach a SQL Server database file from another server

Tags: sql-server, database

I have changed my hard disk. My all databases are on old hard disk. I have attached my old hard disk as external hard disk. Now how can I attach database files from external hard disk to new installed SQL Server?

Comment: Either by using SQL Server Management Studio (Object Explorer > Databases > Attach), or you can do it with a T-SQL statement, too (using e.g. `sqlcmd`)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Or with T-SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-attach-db-transact-sql#examples

Comment: I have tried SQL Server Management Studio but it cant read files from that directory

Comment: You need to **copy the files** to the new server's file system before you can attach them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SQL Server Management Studio to do this:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio `Object Explorer`, connect to an instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine, and then expand that instance.
2. Right-click `Databases` and click `Attach`.
3. In the Attach Databases dialog box, to specify the database to be attached, click `Add`; and in the Locate Database Files dialog box, select the disk drive where the database resides and expand the directory tree to find and select the `.mdf` file of the database;

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209(v=sql.105).aspx

Please note that you need to copy the files to the new server's file system before you can attach them. Thanks [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) for pointing it out.

Comment: I tried this but object Explorer is not showing files in that directory.

Comment: And what files are in that directory?

Comment: yes files are in that directory. It is data directory of older sql server

Comment: I don't understand. Are there `.mdf` files in that directory?

Comment: It has two files of each database, database file and log file.
H:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA

Comment: Are you in the right directory? What if you choose `All files (*.*)` in the filter?

Comment: @Ans Why don't you move those files?

Comment: @Ans If you find this answer helpful, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps:

- Copy/Move your files to "Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\".
- In SSMS, Databases -> Attach